# Updating multiple cells in gspread using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm Inserting values in Google Sheets but the loop doesn't go to the next cell it keeps inserting only in A1 instead of going to A1, A2, etc.

```py
cell_list = wks.range('A1:A200')

    # wks.update('A1', data['_embedded']['events'])
    for k in data['_embedded']['events']:
        i = 0
        cell_list[i].value = k['name']
        wks.update_cells(cell_list)
        i += 1
```

This's an image for the data in the google sheets.
[Google Sheets data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjYVx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

I thought that your commented `wks.update()` will be able to be used.

```py
wks.update("A1", [[e["name"]] for e in data["_embedded"]["events"]], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

When you want to use `wks.update_cells(cell_list)`, in your script, the value is always put to the 1st element by `i = 0`. I think that this is the reason for your issue. So how about the following modification?

```py
cell_list = wks.range("A1:A200")
for i, k in enumerate(data["_embedded"]["events"]):
    cell_list[i].value = k["name"]
wks.update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

#### Reference:

- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html?highlight=update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)

Comment: Thanks it works, but I wanted to make another list to be printed 
`cell_list = wks.range("A1:A200")
cell_list2 = wks.range("B1")
for i, k in enumerate(data["_embedded"]["events"]):
  
    cell_list[i].value = k["name"]
    cell_list2[i].value = k["id"]
wks.update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
wks.update_cells(cell_list2, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")`

it gives an error `  cell_list2[i].value = k["id"]
IndexError: list index out of range` but it prints `k["id"]` normally

Comment: @Jack Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sure, I will create a new question and send you the link here I tried I thought it would work but it doesn't.

Comment: Oh I reached the limit. 
But I can post another answer then you can post another answer also.

Comment: @Jack About `Oh I reached the limit. But I can post another answer then you can post another answer also.`, in that case, it is required to wait for it. When you could post it as a new question, I would like to check it.